# How to test for :terminal support?

Tags: neovim, terminal

I have neovim 0.3.4 installed which means I can run the `:terminal` command, however, doing `:echo has('terminal')` shows `0`.

So, I wonder if there is any other way I can test for its support because all my terminal mappings wrapped within an `if has('terminal)...endif` do not work.

According to the vim manual that is the way to test it

> The terminal feature is optional, use this to check if your Vim has it: 
>           echo has('terminal')
>   If the result is "1" you have it.
>   -- https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html

Thanks

Comment: neovim always has the terminal included, so you can simply use `has('nvim')` the other test is for Vim specifically.

Comment: Exactly, what I needed. Works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by Christian Brabandt in the question's comment:

> neovim always has the terminal included, so you can simply use has('nvim') the other test is for Vim specifically.

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
if exists(':terminal')
```

to check for existence of the `terminal` command.  This works in both vim and neovim.